# NSView -alignmentRectForFrame: not respecting flipped coordinates?

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout, nsview, coordinate-systems

**HEADS-UP:** I write way too much stuff. For the folks who don't want to read a bunch of whining, feel free to skip to the **TL;DR** at the bottom of the page. Thanks!

For the last few weeks, I've been subclassing all of the standard Aqua controls to make them look good on dark backgrounds, panels, and windows. I'm currently pretty far in, and for the most part, things are lookin' good. However, I keep running into the same problems over and over again. They're almost always math-related because I was big screwup in school. (I was that kid who would dismissively ask, "When will I ever use a stem-and-leaf plot in the real world? Ha!" In other words, I bought my TI-86 for Block Dude and Drug Wars. Anyway, I digress …

So the problem that keeps cropping up is my ineptitude when it comes to working with multiple coordinate systems. Specifically, working with Auto Layout in flipped coordinate systems. By default, `NSView` objects use Cartesian coordinates. However, most — if not all — of the `NSControl` classes flip their coordinates for drawing. Knowing that, this is what I've been doing:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    // -isHUDPanel is just a method I added to NSWindow via category.
    if ( controlView.window.isHUDPanel ) {
        [self drawCustomWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    } else {
        [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    }
}
```

If the control's window has the `NSHUDWindowMask` bit set, the `-drawWithFrame:inView:` method kicks it over to my custom method:

```
- (void)drawCustomWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect drawingRect = [controlView alignmentRectForFrame:cellFrame];

    // ...
    // Where the magic happens
    // ...
}
```

Auto Layout still baffles me, so I'm not even sure I'm using `-alignmentRectForFrame:` in the proper context, but it makes sense to me to use it to align stuff when drawing, so that's what I've been doing. Anyway, the problem I've been seeing sometimes when comparing my control side-by-side to a native control is that mine is 1–2 points "off" on one axis or another. Sometimes they align perfectly. Sometimes one axis is great and the other is whacky. It's a crapshoot. Then there are other times when the controls' frames will align just right, but the baselines of the controls' text will be a few points off. It's really maddening.

I finally decided to try some stuff, and it seems as though my alignment troubles may be stemming from the way `NSEdgeInsets` work. For example, let's say my control's bounds look like this:

`NSRect: {{0, 0}, {150, 22}}; // (aka "cellFrame" in the drawing methods)`

In my `-drawWithFrame:inView:` implementation, I first get the control's alignment rectangle by calling `[controlView alignmentRectForFrame:cellFrame]`, which returns, let's say …

`NSRect: {{2, 3}, {146, 19}}`

At first glance, it seems as though the edges on the x-axis are inset by `2.0`, and the `y` origin is `3.0`. With that quick math out of the way, I now know everything I need to get started building `NSBezierPath` objects and going to work. But wait … Is that `y` origin in the control's coordinate system (flipped) or the default coordinate system (not flipped)? Surely it's in the control's, right? Well, I decided to test this out by manually setting the alignmentRect via the control's `-alignmentRectInsets` like so:

```
NSEdgeInsets insets = self.controlView.alignmentRectInsets;
NSRect bounds = self.controlView.bounds;
NSRect alignmentRect = bounds;

alignmentRect.origin.x += insets.left;
alignmentRect.origin.y += (self.controlView.isFlipped) ? insets.top : insets.bottom;
alignmentRect.size.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
alignmentRect.size.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
```

When manually creating the alignmentRect myself, my controls lined up with the native ones! I just don't get it though. Why aren't the controls' `-alignmentRectForFrame:` methods returning their alignmentRects whilst respecting flippedness of the view? I'm not even sure if they all do or not, but from the two controls I've tested this little trick on, the alignment has been on the money.

I've searched all over the web for some insight on this, but nobody seems to have the weird geometry problems I have. I always make these questions way too long, too, and I apologize. I just can't explain my problem when I don't exactly know my problem. :-(

TL;DR: How do I get the proper alignment rectangle for drawing in an NSControl subclass? Is there even a "standard" way? And finally, how does `-cellSize`, `-cellSizeForBounds`, `-baselineOffsetFromBottom`, and `-intrinsicContentSize` all fit together in the grand scheme of things? And final question: Auto Layout … WTF?